# More than one instance of a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I had a look at the JavaScript module pattern but it seems it's only use to create singletons. Is it possible to use the same pattern to create more than one instance of the same module? Or should I look at a different pattern?

Comment: Google for `Pro JavaScript Design Patterns`. Sure you will learn a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Module = (function() {
  return { ... };
}());
```

would create Singleton

```
var createModule = function() {
  return { ... };
}
```

would create a function that creates the module object

```
var ModuleInstance = createModule();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pseudo class with javascript.
Look [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)